# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'kategoria_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, select, html-select

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'kategoria_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sasans` (`kategoria_id`, `fornesedor_id`, `naran`, `data_akisisaun`, `kuantidade`, `marka`, `modelo`, `deskrisaun`, `foto`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, Tixu, 2022-10-17, 67, Leice, Ndaa, GGGGG, public/sasan_image/download (4).jpg, 2022-10-20 05:41:09, 2022-10-20 05:41:09))

Here is may input where I want to catch Kategoria

```
                                    <b>Kategoria:</b>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="show-tick form-control">
                                            <option value="">Hili Kategoria</option>
                                            @foreach ($kategories as $kategoria)
                                            <option value="{{ $kategoria->id }}">{{ $kategoria->naran }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

my table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sasans', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('kategoria_id')->references('id')->on('kategorias')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('fornesedor_id')->references('id')->on('fornesedors')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('naran');
            $table->string('foto');
            $table->date('data_akisisaun');
            $table->integer('kuantidade');
            $table->string('marka');
            $table->string('modelo');
            $table->string('deskrisaun');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // $anexos = $request->file('foto')->store('public/anexos');
        // $naranFoto = substr($anexos, 6, strlen($anexos)-1);

        $sasan_image = $request->file('foto');
        $dalan = $sasan_image->getClientOriginalName();
        $foto = $sasan_image->storeAs('public/sasan_image',$dalan,'');

        $sasan = new Sasan();
        $sasan -> kategoria_id = $request->kategoria_id;
        $sasan -> fornesedor_id = $request->fornesedor_id;
        $sasan -> naran = $request->naran;
        $sasan -> data_akisisaun = $request->data_akisisaun;
        $sasan -> kuantidade = $request->kuantidade;
        $sasan -> marka = $request->marka;
        $sasan -> modelo = $request->modelo;
        $sasan -> deskrisaun = $request->deskrisaun;
        $sasan -> foto = $foto;

        $sasan->save();
        // Alert::success('Rejista Ona','Kategoria Sasan Regista ona ho Sucesso');
        return redirect()->back()->with('success','Sasan Rejista ona.');
    }
```

Comment: `<select class="show-tick form-control">` needs a `name` attribute or it never gets sent to the server code. So `<select name="kategoria_id" class="show-tick form-control">`

Comment: Thanks a lot @RiggsFolly.
Its work for me

I added name and Id to my Select tag

`<select class="show-tick form-control" id="kategoria_id" name="kategoria_id">`

Comment: OK, the `id` attribute has nothing to do with getting the field posted to the server by the browser, that is used to address the element from javascript

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have a not nullable `kategoria_id` field and you need to make sure that it has a value when you insert or update a record. At this point:

```
$sasan -> kategoria_id = $request->kategoria_id;
```

the value you receive is already `null`. As a result, it's not being sent in the first place. And the reason is...

that you do not have a `name` attribute specified for your `select` tag. You will need to specify such a `name`:

```
 <select class="show-tick form-control" name="kategoria_id">
```